# Change Chef Server Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, knife

I'm using AWS to host my Chef server, and I've connected to it from my workstation using Knife. However, after shutting down and turning the server on, the Public DNS changed, and I'm unable to reconnect to the server, resulting in this message:

```
ERROR: Error connecting to https://*.compute-1.amazonaws.com/organizations/*/cookbooks?num_versions=all
```

Is there any way to change the address of the Chef server on the workstation without making the workstation think it's connecting to an entirely new server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `reconfigure` the Chef Server, possibly updating it's config file first to ensure the right hostname is in the right places. After that, make sure you update the `chef_server_url` in the knife.rb or client.rb of every machine.